# Question on discontinuity

Tags: real-analysis

If I know that $g ∈ R[a,b]$, and $f$ is continuous, how would I show that disc$(f∘g)$ ⊆  disc $(g)$?

I know to use the Lebesgue theorem which states that a bounded function is integrable $⇔$ the discontinuous set of the function has measure zero. But I'm failing to connect the dots.

I was looking at other questions and someone suggested using the fact that if $g$ is continuous at $x$ and f is continuous at $g()$, then $f∘g$ is continuous at $$. Could I use this to show that disc$(f∘g)$ ⊆  disc $(g)$? If not, what is another approach I could take?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

False. Let $g(x)=0$ for $x \in (0,1]$ and $g(0)=1$. Let $f(x) =1-x$. Then $g\circ f$ is discontinuous at $1$ even though $g$ is continuous at $1$.

Answer for the edited version: This has nothing to do with Riemann integrability. If $g$ is continuous at $x$ and $f$ is a continuous function then $f(g(x))$ is continuous at $x$; the contra-positive gives $disc(f\circ g) \subseteq disc (g)$.

Comment: Sorry, I don't see the connection between this question and the link.

Comment: Ahh silly mistake; I meant to write disc$(∘)$ ⊆ disc $()$ in my question and not disc$(g∘f)$ ⊆ disc $()$ because this latter statement is false. Apologies.